# Run a specific main dart file while running the android application

Tags: android, flutter

I have a native android application that in some flows I integrate with flutter screens so I have a flutter module within the android project and I have made all the setup and everything is working as expected. But in flutter project I have two main files one for production and one for development
`main.dart` for the production and `main_dev.dart` for the development.
Now my question is -> How to make flutter project run `main_dev.dart` while debugging (running debug build on android) and run `main.dart` while releasing (running release build on android).

The only way to do this now every time I run the debug version I have to rename both files so the `main.dart` becomes `old_main.dart` and `main_dev.dart` becomes `main.dart`